# Lines not behaving as they should

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, line

I am making a small program to simulate somekind piece of string, and I want it so that I can move middle parts of the string and the other parts move with it, I made the string out of segments of lines. Here's a picture of how it looks now.

[image]

As you can see, the top part of the string is behaving as it should, now my trouble is at making the bottom part work, can I have any help with this? The code I am using for the upper part is:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < segmentsCount - 1; i++) 
        {
            stringLines[i].lineEndPos = stringLines[i + 1].lineStartPos;
            stringLines[i].startSpeedX = stringLines[i + 1].startSpeedX / 1.1f;
        }
```

Comment: If the upper part works but the bottom part doesn't, then we'd like to see the code for the bottom part, too. The code here seems incomplete. Where do you use startSpeedX? What do you actually draw? Finally, the png doesn't load for me.

Comment: @redtuna I updated the post, it should display the picture now, startSpeedX just increments to the position of the rope, currently there's no code for the bottom part, because I thought this would solve it completely, the first line basically makes it so that all the lines stay together, and the second line makes it so that the top part moves with the segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that instead of a single loop from 0 to  segmentsCount - 1, you want two loops, each computing the positions away from the point where the user is holding the rope. Perhaps something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < segmentsHeld - 1; i++) 
{
    stringLines[i].lineEndPos = stringLines[i + 1].lineStartPos;
    stringLines[i].startSpeedX = stringLines[i + 1].startSpeedX / 1.1f;
}

for (int i = segmentCount-1; i > segmentHeld; i--) 
{
    stringLines[i].lineEndPos = stringLines[i - 1].lineStartPos;
    stringLines[i].startSpeedX = stringLines[i - 1].startSpeedX / 1.1f;
}
```